# Move Batch files to folder with similar name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to move batch files to their respective folder, they have similar names expect the batch files I want to move have "Build" on the end. For example:

Folder name: wld-vine-tstrm

Bat file name: wld-vine-tstrmBuild.bat

In the same parent directory, I also have batch files with  identical names to the folder, I do not want these to move, only the ones with "Build" at the end of the file names.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath=E:\Build\ModelBatches\world-wild\actor50
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.bat) do (
  set "foldername=%%~nf"
  move "%%f" "!foldername:~0,-5!"
)
```

This is very close to the result I am looking for; it moves the "Build" batches to the respective folder, but it also removes the last 5 characters from the batches I dont want to move.

[image: Correctly moved batch files]

The below batch files are now missing the last 5 chars, "tstrm"

[image: Renamed batch file]

To summarize, There are two batch files for each folder in a directory, I only want to move the one ending "Build" to its folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch copy/move files to folders with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453880/batch-copy-move-files-to-folders-with-same-name)

Comment: Why don't you use `*Build.bat` instead of `*.bat` then?

Comment: That worked, not sure how I missed it.
Thanks.

Comment: Change the `move` command line to `move "%%~f" "!foldername:~0,-5!\"` (note the trailing backslash), so you force the destination to be interpreted as a folder and avoid files to become renamed...

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set folderpath=E:\Build\ModelBatches\world-wild\actor50 
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*build.bat) do ( 
  set "foldername=%%~nf" 
  move "%%f" "!foldername:~0,-5!" 
)
```

The wildcard `*build.bat` finds all batch files ending with "build" but wildcard "*.bat" shows them all.

Comment: Wasif Hasan, is there a particular reason why you have a tendency to repeat other people's comments, as answers, both before confirmation by the OP, and, _in this case_, after both a comment and answer confirmation? It is clear on this occasion that your answer has not solved anything, I have.

Comment: No I started to answer it before the OP answered it.

Comment: Unless it took at least 20 minutes to type, it is technically still a repeat of my earlier, comment, _(isn't it)?_

Comment: Anyway, thank you. I will try to reduce these sorts of answers. The credit goes to you.

Comment: @com: If you know the answer, why are you posting a comment?

Comment: Because @IInspectable, in my opinion the question was essentially an oversight by the OP, and not something which by answering would be of use to future searchers/questioners. In cases such as this, I do not feel the need to inflate my reputation/points tally unnecessarily.

Comment: @com: In that case you should have voted to close the question.

Comment: I thought I had, @IInspectable, now corrected as if a typo.